# Why you can't access a TypeScript nested elements even if you export

Tags: typescript

I have a simple interface:

```
export interface AmazingToolKit {
AmazingClass: {
    amazingProperty: boolean;
};
```

}

But when I try and access

```
 var a:AmazingToolKit.AmazingClass.amazingProperty;
```

The compiler is giving me

Error:(63, 15) TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'AmazingToolKit'.

however if I do single level, all is fine.. seems like a bug :/

any idea?

tx

Sean

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in your code, though I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here. `AmazingToolKit.AmazingClass` is an interface member, not a type, so you can't use it in place of a type. Here's some made up code that does work:

```
export namespace AmazingToolkit {
  export class AmazingClass {
    amazingProperty: boolean;
  }
}

var a = new AmazingToolkit.AmazingClass();
var b = a.amazingProperty;
```

Comment: tx, what I wanted to do is cast a member to be of type a:AmazingToolKit.AmazingClass.amazingProperty instead of having to create seperate interfaces and nest references in each sub interface, regards